# Jquery Plugin conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a slider and and news ticker in my home page.

I have used following coding in head tag.

```
[1]<script type="text/javascript" src="..js/jquery.core.js"></script>
[2]<script type="text/javascript" src="..js/jquery.superfish.js"></script>
[3]<script type="text/javascript" src="..js/jquery.jcarousel.pack.js"></script>
[4]<script type="text/javascript" src="..js/jquery.easing.js"></script>
[5]<script type="text/javascript" src="..js/jquery.scripts.js"></script>
[6]<script type="text/javascript" src="..js/common.js"></script>
```

When I use this format my slider works fine but the news ticker get stuck.
The slider use 2nd, 3rd, 4th, and 5th script.
The 6th script is for the news ticker.
If I use the the 6th script after the first the news ticker works fine. But then the slider doesn't work.

How should I use them to get both working?

Thanks.

Comment: If I were in your position, I just wouldn't use frameworks. No frameworks, no conflicts because I would name my script elements separately (or better yet enclose them in their own closures so there are no global variables left behind)

Comment: @Kolink I think that's too strict. How about reading the source and verifying quality before using the plugin/framework? But I guess most jQuery plugins don't pass this anyway so is there really much difference :D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I solve this jQuery plugins conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531227/how-do-i-solve-this-jquery-plugins-conflict)

Answer (score 1):

If the plugins are truly incompatible, and you don't want to edit them to fix the conflicts, it may be a solution to put one of them in an iframe to isolate it...
Especially if they are isolated components that don't communicate back to the rest of the page...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof jQuery !== 'undefined') {
    jQuery.noConflict();
}
</script>
```

use the above code between 5th and 6th script, and use **`jQuery`** instead of **`$`** in 6th js, it might be helpful