# Can I use something other than $ to prevent conflict between jQuery plugins?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two plugins, both which use their own .swipe() function: `ex: $("div").swipe();`

Is it possible to give one of the plugins a different variable instead of `$`?

For example, could I use `jQ("div").swipe();` for plugin A and `$("div").swipe();` for plugin B?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: I suppose you could load jquery twice and use `noConflict`... just so messy

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115174/jquery-plugin-conflicts

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, however it would be better to instead rename the plugin.

```
<script src="jquery.swipe.js"></script>
<script>
    $.fn.swipeOne = $.fn.swipe;
</script>
<script src="jQuery.swipeTwo.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#swipeone").swipeOne();
    $("#swipetwo").swipe();
});
</script>
```

Otherwise you would have to include jQuery twice.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you want the noConflict option.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Better example of how to use it:

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Answer (score 2):

If both jQuery plugins need to be bound to the same jQuery object, go in either one plugin, and look for `$.fn.swipe`. Change the word "swipe" to anything you like (e.g. `$.fn.mySwipe`), bearing in mind that its internal references to the word "swipe" might also need to change.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
jq(function) {

})
```

and then just refer to jq

Comment: Where is `jq` defined?

Comment: at jq(function(){   - you simply define the variable to use instead of the $ sign

Comment: I think you mean `$(function(jq){...})` or `(function(jq){...})($)`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the $ by using

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Now you'd use `$j` whenver you'd use `$` before, e.g.,

```
$j(document).ready(function() {
    //stuff
}
```